# Unhandled exception after adding a pointer to an object

Tags: c++, directx

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00a57647 in PhysicsDemo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00b9bd16.
```

I keep getting this error when running my code. it brings me too...

```
static void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right)
    {   // assign an element
    _Left = _Right;
    }
```

and I'm not sure where to look. I tired placing breakpoints around my code to locate where the error was coming from, but I could not find it. Can someone give me the general idea of what this error is caused by? I don't need specifics for my code ( Which is why I didn't provide you any. It is too large. ) I just want to know what causes this?

Comment: the `_Left` is is a dangling reference or a reference obtained by dereferencing an invalid pointer. one way to create a dangling reference is to return a reference to a local object. one way to create an invalid pointer is to `delete`. since you're doing window stuff you can simply look at the call stack in visual studio. run the program via `F5` (debugging), when it crashes break and check out the stack trace view.

Comment: In addition to what Alf said, `_Elem` could have a problem in the implementation of the `=` operator.  This is unlikely if it is part of the library, but if you wrote it you may want to double check.